# Initialization of variable was never used, what do i do?

Tags: swift

```
 var Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

After this it tells me that the variable 'timer' was never used, what do i do?
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you will not use the variable Timer later, just use

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

or

```
_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: I wish they had worded it, "After initialization, variable xyz was never used." Then it would've been more clear. The way they worded it made me think that something about the initialization process wasn't being used, which baffled me as a Swift beginner (ie, I thought this was a new concept I needed to learn, not just that the variable isn't used in the function after being instantiated). Splitting hairs, I know, but it's interesting how the omission of one word and a comma made the sentence's meaning obscure for me. Anyway, your answer clarified it, so thanks.